# Bash script to use keytab without writing it to disk

Tags: bash, encryption, pipe, kerberos, keytab

I have an encrypted keytab which I'm decrypting, writing it to disk and then using it with kinit.

What I want to do is to be able use the keytab without writing it to disk, just decrypt and use it directly with kinit. Here is my script thus far but I get
kinit: Key table file '/etc/krb5.keytab' not found while getting initial credentials

```
#!/bin/bash
#$KEYTAB = gpg --decrypt keytab.gpg
$KEYTAB=keytab
kinit -k $KEYTAB principal@realm
```

I also am trying with a pipe

```
gpg --decrypt keytab.gpg | kinit -k principal@realm
```

but that's not working either.

Comment: Hm, in my man page for kinit, the option `-k` is described with: "The same as --keytab, but with the default keytab name (normally FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab)." You might want to try `gpg --decrypt keytab.gpg | .kinit -k -t - ...`  but I am not too confident, in that this solves the problem.

Comment: As comment edits are only allowed for 5 minutes, I amend here: The suggestion was to replace the filename with `-` and to fiddle the `principal@realm` info into the process via something like `-S ...` option.

Comment: `$KEYTAB=keytab` should be `KEYTAB=keytab`.

Comment: @chepner great the worked for the unencrypted one :)

Comment: I've tried for the encrypted with `KEYTAB="$(gpg --decrypt keytab.gpg)"
` but haven't been able to get it pass

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, kinit needs to read the keytab from a file cannot be passed a variable.

http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/user/user_commands/kinit.html

Comment: What is your concern: that the file does not remain on the disk media after finishing kinit?

Comment: The opposite, that it is written to disk. The aim was to pass it as a variable and not write to disk.

Answer (score 0):

As long as kinit just reads the file, use /dev/stdin

```
gpg --decrypt keytab.gpg | kinit -k /dev/stdin principal@realm
```

Another example with another program

```
echo foo | cat /dev/stdin
```

Comment: It's not asking me for the password to decrypt keytab.gpg... Also it doesn't seem like it will work as echo keytab | kinit -k /dev/stdin principal@realm or echo keytab | kinit -k -t /dev/stdin principal@realm  do not work

Comment: I do not know why.  I created a gpg file and the following asks for a passphrase: `gpg -d x.gpg | cat /dev/stdin`

Comment: I tried a couple of times, the furtherest i get is `kinit: Keytab contains no suitable keys for principal@realm while getting initial credential` with `gpg --decrypt keytab.gpg | kinit -k -t /dev/stdin principal@realm`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work *without* writing to disk, but with mktemp it does what I need. I have a base64 encoded string from Vault.

```
f=$(mktemp); printf "$b64keytab" | base64 -d > $f; kinit -f -kt $f principal@realm; rm -f $f
```

With gpg it should be like below.

```
f=$(mktemp); gpg --decrypt keytab.gpg > $f; kinit -f -kt $f principal@realm; rm -f $f
```